# "Add as favorite" from tag hover popup

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

When I hover my mouse over a tag, I would love to be able to add it as a favorite. As it it, the only hover actions possible are "subscribe" and "rss". Or have I missed something? I would use this functionality way more often than the other two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking the star in the top left-hand corner will favourite the tag, as explained by the tooltip:

[image: Favourite star tooltip]