# be able to add tags into "Favourite Tags" or "Ignored Tags" when you hover over the tag in the question

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

I was wondering if it would be possible able to add tags into "Favourite Tags" or "Ignored Tags" when you hover over the tag in the question (currently it displays brief overview about the tag and subsribe/rss links).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to the ignore option in the mouseover on the tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/what-happened-to-the-ignore-option-in-the-mouseover-on-the-tags), ["Add as favorite" from tag hover popup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81989)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Add as favorite" from tag hover popup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81989/add-as-favorite-from-tag-hover-popup)