# Ignore Tags in Tag Hover Popup

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

When browsing lists of questions in one of the tabs (interesting, hot, etc) there is a summary of each question.

On each summary entry (among other things) the questions tags are surfaced.

When hovering over one of these tags, the tag popup is shown containing several links ("faq" "top users", "edit", "subscribe", "rss").

My feature request is similar to the [request to add favorite control to this UI element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81989/add-as-favorite-from-tag-hover-popup).

Please link "ignore" so that clicking it would add the tag to your Ignored Tag List.

This would allow for one-click addition to your tag lists, precisely at the point that you notice they need to be favorited or ignored - without interrupting your flow to scroll the page to the top and type out the tag name.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Add as favorite" from tag hover popup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81989/add-as-favorite-from-tag-hover-popup)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's already there. Click on the star to add the tag to your favorites. Click on it a second time to add it to your ignored tags.

Click it a third time to forget the whole thing.

(There is a tool-tip that says basically the same thing.)

Comment: Its super discoverable!

Comment: The top left is not a very discoverable place to put a button, especially when it has no 3d, no button frame and has the focus taken away by text links.  Why not change it to be text links like the others.

Comment: >shrug<. I'm not the UI guy.

Comment: ULTRA hidden. Gotta be a ninja to discover that.